# c++ float to sql server DECIMAL correct conversion

Tags: c++, sql, odbc

I am creating an application in native c++ using odbc. I am calling on to a sql server stored procedure that has a decimal parameter. I am passing a float to that parameter. The code so far:

```
    SQLDECIMAL *sql_param = new SQLDECIMAL( param);
if( SQL_ERROR == ( result = SQLBindParameter( statement_handle, 5, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_FLOAT, SQL_DECIMAL, 12, 6, sql_param, 0, NULL ) ) ){
    std::wstring error = get_error_message( SQL_HANDLE_STMT, statement_handle );

    throw GenericException( error );
}
```

param is a float.

What gets stored on the table is always 0 instead of the real value which is 1.45. I'm guessing some conversion is taking place but I can't figured out the correct conversion. SQL_C_FLOAT -> SQL_DECIMAL?

Answer (score 2):

In the [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms710963%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
SQLRETURN SQLBindParameter(
      SQLHSTMT        StatementHandle,
      SQLUSMALLINT    ParameterNumber,
      SQLSMALLINT     InputOutputType,
      SQLSMALLINT     ValueType,
      SQLSMALLINT     ParameterType,
      SQLULEN         ColumnSize,
      SQLSMALLINT     DecimalDigits,
      SQLPOINTER      ParameterValuePtr,
      SQLLEN          BufferLength,
      SQLLEN *        StrLen_or_IndPtr);
...

BufferLength
[Input/Output] Length of the ParameterValuePtr buffer in bytes.
```

You have specified `BufferLength` as zero. Looking [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx), you can see the length of decimal for different precision values:

```
Precision      StorageBytes
1-9             5
10-19           9
20-28           13
29-38           17
```

Therefore, you need to call  method `SQLBindParameter` as:

```
SQLBindParameter( statement_handle, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_FLOAT, SQL_DECIMAL, 12, 6, sql_param, 5, NULL )
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. I've modified the code to use 5 as the buffer lenght. I've also tried 10, 15, etc... and it still stores 0 in the field.

Reading the documentation on SQLBindParameter further, it seems that   that parameter is sometimes ignored (but i'm not sure if in this case it is being ignored). I've read and reread the documentation, it just isn't going to my head. :D

Answer (score 2):

The SQLDECIMAL is your problem. According to http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/soliddb/v6r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.soliddb.programmer.doc/doc/s0005314.c.data.types.html it is a unsigned char [f].
I suggest something like:

```
void bind_float(float* param) {
    SQLBindParameter( statement_handle, 5, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_FLOAT, SQL_DECIMAL, 12, 6, param, 0, NULL ) ) );
}
```

Comment: I finally got it. Your answer was close enough. It shouldn't have been `SQLDECIMAL *sql_param = new SQLDECIMAL( param );`. It should have been `SQLDECIMAL *sql_param = (SQLDECIMAL *) param;`

Comment: Am I getting it totally wrong: You have a float (SQL_C_FLOAT) as parameter no SQLDECIMAL

Answer (score 1):

I got it. It shouldn't have been:

`SQLDECIMAL *sql_param = new SQLDECIMAL( param );`

it should have been:

`SQLDECIMAL *sql_param = (SQLDECIMAL *) param;`